# error connecting to mysql database through crazy domains

Tags: php, mysqli

newbie here! I have made a simple form on my site

[warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLKb8.png)

I can't seem to figure out what i've done wrong.

This is the php code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "charityh_root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "charitydb";

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

//$password = $_POST['password'];
//$sha1password = sha1($password);

//Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

//Check connection
If ($conn -> connect_error) {
die("Connection failed:" . $conn -> connect_error);

}
```

Line 17 is `$conn = newmysqli($...`

any idea guys?

[Mysql database wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVyDC.png)

Connecting to database now although when i enter in the details (first name, last name, state and email) i get the message first name can not be left blank...

```
if (empty($fname)) {
    Echo "First name can not be blank. Please press back and correct the 
    issue";
    die();

 }

 if (empty($lname)) {
Echo "Last name can not be blank. Please press back and correct the issue!";
die();

}

if (empty($state)) {
  Echo "State can not be blank. Please press back and correct the issue!";
  die();

}

if (empty($email)) {
    Echo "Email can not be blank. Please press back and correct the issue!";
die();

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO charityh_database (First_Name, Last_Name, State, Email)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$state', '$email')";

  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Thank You";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

  $conn->close ();

   ?>
```

Comment: Please confirm if you have a password and this is set correctly in your code. You seem to state in one of your other comments that you do, but your code shows no password. This is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dbusername = "charityh_root";
$dbpassword = "";
```

Seems like you are using the same username and password as you were using in your local server. You need to replace them with the username and password crazy domain's.

Since as far as I know Crazy Domain deosn't allows a blank password.

**EDIT**
Besides that I can see the database name you have mentioned in the codes is "charitydb"; which should be something like charityh_database.(By looking at your recent edit this is a wild guess)

Comment: Hi Amit yes i actually have a password but still getting the same error. should i make a whole new db through crazy domains again with a different username and password

Comment: Nope that's not necessary. All you need is to take care of four values. DBNAME, USERNAME.PWD, AND HOSTNAME.

Comment: Besides that I can see the database name you have mentioned in the codes is "charitydb"; which should be something like charityh_database.(By looking at your recent edit this is a wild guess)

Comment: You are right Amit i have changed it to charityh_database, which seems to be working but name im getting the error of the first name can't be left blank... even though i have filled in the first name let me copy the rest of the code in my question and are you able to have a look to see if it is right?

Comment: sorry i thought i already gave it sorry ill do it now. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates your username and password do not have access to the database.

Have you checked the database will allow you to connect, using the username and password?

Comment: Hi Karl i am able to log into phpmyadmin although it doesn't ask me for a username and password. is that the way to check if i can connect. sorry for my noobness

Comment: Is it remembering your username and password? Can you log out of the DB and log back in again?