# Select data from a row in database

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, session

I am making a profile page in which I want the user's email to be displayed. I thought this would be quite a simple code that could be achieved using the select function from the database. However, this only works for one string and I cannot seem to figure out why.

This is my original code

```
session_start();

$_SESSION["user"] = $username;
$_SESSION["pass"] = $password;
$_SESSION["email"] = $email;
$connection = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "root", "", "picshare");

if ($connection ->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}else{

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT email FROM login WHERE username='".$_SESSION["user"]."'");
$field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 

    if (!$query)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        $field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);


}else{
echo "error";
$conn->close();

    }}
```

When I try and echo $field, nothing was echoed

```
            <p class ="right uc"><?php       echo($field['email']);?></p>
```

I retried the code, but instead of using a session, I made a variable

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "picshare";
$user = 'Eniola Olaogun';

$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}else{

$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT email FROM login WHERE username='".$user."'");
$field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 

    if (!$query)
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
        $field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
        echo($field['email']);

}else{
echo "error";
$conn->close();
```

This code displayed the email, and so I proceeded to change the $user variable to another name and the original problem occurred where nothing was echoed.

I went back to the original code and I logged in as Eniola Olaogun and the email was echoed, but as soon as I changed the person I logged in as, no email was echoed.

I am not sure why I am experiencing this problem and some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `mysqli_error($con)` that won't work, you're using a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
$host = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "picshare";
$user = 'Eniola Olaogun';

$conn = new mysqli ($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
else {
$sql = "SELECT email FROM login WHERE username= {$user}";
$result = $conn->query($sql); 

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        echo($row['email']);
}
else {
echo "error";
$conn->close();
```

Answer (score -1):

[error connecting to mysql database through crazy domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34286401/error-connecting-to-mysql-database-through-crazy-domains)

It sounds like it is a permission issue based on the user you're logging in as.

Test it with a 'root' user password that has global access and then troubleshoot and isolate it from there.  I'm betting you will find it then.

Pretty much impossible for me to test this remotely since I don't have your DB schema and user accounts to validate with.